# 3 JEDEC timing table vs 4 (Memory)

Tags: memory, memory-timings

Here's my old memory, which was one 4gb stick.

[image]

Now I upgraded to two of these (total 8gb);

[image]

Notice the timings table are different.  Obviously the new RAM timings are faster, but there's only 3 JEDEC slots, and the old one had 4 (maybe 7??).

I am trying to find a clear answer on if this is good or bad or what it means !

Answer (score 3):

The SPD tells you the capabilities of each memory stick. You should look into the Memory tab to find  the mode that your system board is actually running for the installed memory.

The JEDEC slots give the primary, secondary timings and voltage that a BIOS can use to automatically set the memory at given FSB speeds. With more RAM, your motherboard seems to have less options available.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the timing of the two modules are differnt.  Just becuase you purchased a memory module that is the same size and clock rate doesn't mean that their timings are the same.  Without knowing the exactly module type of the Micron, [I couldn't tell if your module](http://www.micron.com/~/media/Documents/Products/Data%20Sheet/Modules/6714ktf16c256_512_1gx64hz.pdf) was a 11-11-11, 9-9-9, or 7-7-7.  But your [Corsair module](http://www.corsair.com/us/vengeance-4gb-high-performance-sodimm-memory-upgrade-kit-cmsx4gx3m1a1600c9.html) is definitely 9-9-9-24

When purchasing memory you need to take the timings into consideration as well (though you probably won't really see a significant change between the different settings).

You should also realize that you're loking at different slots as well.  Slot one will have JDEC #'s 1-3 and Slot two will have JDEC #'s 4-7.  So your original module didn't have 7 timings.

*Note: smaller timing are considered better if I remember correctly.*

Comment: The original was 9-9-9-24.  When I go to slot 2, it also lists JEDEC #1-3.

Comment: @Joshua What's the timing of the new one? And I'm not exactly sure what it is you're looking to get answered... is it the fact that there are more JDEC's for the old one than the new one?

Comment: *>  Slot one will have JDEC #'s 1-3 and Slot two will have JDEC #'s 4-7.*   So slot one has three and slot two has four? `o.O`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be that the they both have different voltages. The less the voltage is, the higher quality the ram is. Kingston still sells DDR3 1600 cas 9 that requires 1.65v to reach that speed. Those are very low quality compared to literally every other company that has moved to 1.5v DDR3 1600 cas 9. AMD processors are less sensitive to RAM voltage than Intel processors so the Kingston is aimed at AMD users.